# Loading form data not clearing validation error message in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

Iam a newbie in Angular2 .

I have a model driven reactive form having four fields lets say a , b , c , d .

Value of input d is populated from a rest service as soon as value of a , b , c is entered by the user .

I have a validation already existing on d such that only value of the form HH:MM:SS should be entered .

**Issue** - After entering value of  a , b , c , i get appropriate response from rest service i.e value of the form HH:MM:SS for field d . However validation error message still remains there . I want this validation error message to be removed as soon as field is populated by rest backend service .

**PS** - This validation message is removed if a value of the form HH:MM:SS is entered manually by the user .

My HTML code is as follows -

```
 <input type="text" name="d" [value]="app.d" 
  formControlName="d">
   <div *ngIf="updateform.controls['d']"> 
      <p *ngIf="updateform.controls['d'].hasError('invalidDuration')">
        Please enter value in HH:MM:SS
      </p>
   </div>
```

Component.ts

```
 app:app_type={
   a : '' ,
   b : '' ,
   c : '' ,
   d : '' 
  };


ngOnInit () { 
this.updateform = new FormGroup ({
d: new FormControl("",validateDuration) })
}

// this method is called whenever values of a , b , c is entered 
checkValueExists(selectedValue:string){

let aa = this.updateform.controls['a'].value;
let bb = this.updateform.controls['b'].value;
let cc = this.updateform.controls['c'].value;

if (aa&&bb&&bb){
let query ="aa="+aa+"&&bb="+bb+"&&cc="+cc
this._service.getDetails(query)
.subscribe(
  result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.app=result;
  });

 }

}
```

Service

```
    getDetails(query:string):Observable<app_type>{
    let url="http://localhost:9001/ang/webapi/abc"
    console.log(url)
    let temp = url + "/?" + query;
    console.log(temp)
    return this.http.get(url + "/?" + query, this.options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
}  
private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Validator.ts

```
export function validateDuration(control: AbstractControl) {
if (!control.value.match(/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/)) {
  return { 'invalidDuration': true};
 }
 return null ;
}
```

Comment: where do you set the value from the server's response?

Comment: @HarryNinh code updated . Please have a look.

Comment: Is this the entire component or have you still got content not shown here? Like initializing the formGroup with the rest of the controls and all?

Comment: Also, can you give a sample response of how your `getDetails()` response look like?

Comment: @amal please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix reactive form with `[value]`. Remove it from the control:

```
<input type="text" name="d" formControlName="d">
```

Set it in your code when receiving the value from service:

```
this._service.getDetails(query)
  .subscribe(
    result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.app=result;
      this.updateform.get('d').setValue(result.d);
    });
```

Comment: I have a question , so [value] terminology should be used only in template drive forms , and shall i remove the usage of [value] from the remaining fields as well ?

Comment: thanks @Harry for the answer your solutions works could you please provide answer to my above comment please .

Comment: `[value]` is just to set the value to the input, nothing more, nothing less. You use it without any form module. `[(ngModel)]` is used in template-driven form, and `formControlName` plus code-behind is used in model-driven form.